# Java 8 function that always return the same value without regarding to parameter

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

Is there a predefined Function in Java 8 that does something like this:

```
static <T, R> Function<T, R> constant(R val) {
    return (T t) -> {
        return val;
   };
}
```

To answer people's query on why I need this function here is the real usage when I am trying to parse an integer to an roman numerals:

```
// returns the stream of roman numeral symbol based
// on the digit (n) and the exponent (of 10)
private static Stream<Symbol> parseDigit(int n, int exp) {
    if (n < 1) return Stream.empty();
    Symbol base = Symbol.base(exp);
    if (n < 4) {
        return IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> base);
    } else if (n == 4) {
        return Stream.of(base, Symbol.fifth(exp));
    } else if (n < 9) {
        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(Symbol.fifth(exp)),
            IntStream.range(5, n).mapToObj(i -> base));
    } else { // n == 9 as n always < 10
        return Stream.of(base, Symbol.base(exp + 1));
    }
}
```

And I guess the `IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> base)` could be simplified to something like `Stream.of(base).times(n - 1)`, unfortunately there is no `times(int)` method on stream object. Does anyone know how to make it?

Comment: Can you give an example where having a function like _constant_ would be useful?

Comment: Also interested in a use case. As far as I can see, plain `x -> 5` would be more or less equivalent to `constant(5)`, but I feel like I may have missed something :)

Comment: x -> 5 is exactly I am looking for! can you put it into the answer?

Comment: I can think of the following usecase: `Map<Whatever,Integer> counter = new HashMap<>(); Integer count = counter.computeIfAbsent(key, _ -> 0); counter.put(key, count + 1);`. It would be nice to read something like `counter.computeIfAbsent(key, Constant::of(0));`

Comment: As for your second question, either of these would achieve your `times(int)` functionality: `Stream.generate(() -> base).limit(n - 1)` or `Collections.nCopies(n - 1, base).stream()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple lambda, `x -> val` seems to be equivalent to your method;

```
Function<Integer, Integer> test1 = constant(5);
Function<Integer, Integer> test2 = x -> 5;
```

...both ignore the input and output the constant 5 when applied;

```
> System.out.println(test1.apply(2));
5
> System.out.println(test2.apply(2));
5
```